# In Crystal Reports 2008 class DatabaseFieldDefinition property UseCount is not [deprecated] - what is a proper way to code now?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2008

In C# Visual Studio 2010, Crystal Reports 2008 (v12) I'm running into a problem. 
The following code is marked as obsolete, and SAP Crystal API suggests to not use it anymore.
However I cannot find a suitable replacement.

```
// in the code below field UseCount is obsolete
foreach (DatabaseFieldDefinition fieldDefinition in table.Fields)
{
    if (fieldDefinition.UseCount > 0)
        listOfFieldDefinitions.Add(fieldDefinition);
}
```

I found that there is a replacement for **Parameter Fields** (class ParameterField) - there is now an extended property called "ParameterFieldUsage2". But I need something similar for **regular fields** on the reports (class DatabaseFieldDefinition).

Crystal designer knows about the fact that field is used somewhere - it marks it with a green check box if a field is used in the rendering, grouping, sorting, or any formulas.

Example 1:
  My report uses fields A, B and C, groups by D, and formula has E and F.
  My code analyses the report, figures out how to procure A, B, C, D, E, F and returns the XML with the necessary data, and then renders a report.

Example 1:
  My report uses fields A, and C, groups by A, and formula has F.
  My code analyses the report, figures out how to procure A, C, F and returns the XML with the much smaller dataset, and then renders a report.

In Crystal .NET (v9) I used to be able to use "UseCount" property as indicated above. What is the proper transition for this?

SAP thread on the 
http://scn.sap.com/thread/2127492